# Find cause of circular import error Python

Tags: python, circular-dependency

I get a circular import error:

```
Exception has occurred: ImportError
cannot import name 'MyTree' from partially initialized module 'user_interface.dragdrop.mytree' (most likely due to a circular import) (c:\Users\xx\Desktop\xx\xx\MyProject\user_interface\dragdrop\mytree.py)
  File "C:\Users\xx\Desktop\xx\xx\MyProject\user_interface\dragdrop\test.py", line 7, in <module>
    from user_interface.dragdrop.mytree import MyTree
  File "C:\Users\xx\Desktop\xx\xx\MyProject\user_interface\dragdrop\mouse.py", line 4, in <module>
    from user_interface.dragdrop.test import TreeItem
  File "C:\Users\xx\Desktop\xx\xx\MyProject\user_interface\dragdrop\mytree.py", line 5, in <module>
    from user_interface.dragdrop.mouse import Mouse
  File "C:\Users\xx\Desktop\xx\xx\MyProject\user_interface\dragdrop\test.py", line 7, in <module>
    from user_interface.dragdrop.mytree import MyTree
```

I have tried to trace back the circular problem by following all the imports, in the order of execution, so starting with the main file. This is described below:

- test.py (main file) imports:

  - `from user_interface.dragdrop.mytree import MyTree`
- mytree.py file imports :

  - `from user_interface.dragdrop.hoverevent import HoverEvent`
  - `from user_interface.dragdrop.mouse import Mouse`
- hoverevent.py imports nothing
- mouse.py imports:

  - `from user_interface.dragdrop.eventmanager import EventManager`
  - `from user_interface.dragdrop.hoverevent import HoverEvent`
  - `from user_interface.dragdrop.singleton import Singleton`
  - `from user_interface.dragdrop.test import TreeItem`
- eventmanager.py imports nothing
- singleton.py imports nothing
- treeitem.py imports nothing

I cannot match my analysis with the error message. In fact, the error message doesn't make much sense to me at all. It seems to indicate that after importing Mouse, test.py (the main file) is imported again. But this is not the case.

Could you please help my find out what is wrong here? Many thanks in advance.

**Edit**: never mind. I found it.

Comment: ```test.py``` imports ```MyTree``` from ```mytree```, which imports ```Mouse``` from ```mouse```, which imports ```TreeItem``` from ```test```, which most likely tries to import ```MyTree``` from ```mytree```...

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I found it.

```
from user_interface.dragdrop.test import TreeItem
```

TreeItem was moved to treeitem.py. It doesnt exist in test.py. After changing that, I dont get the error any more.

Thanks anyway.